# Short circuit evaluation of a statement with ++ operator in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence, short-circuiting

I have executed the following code in Code::Blocks 10.05 on Windows 7.

```
int a=0,b=0,c;
c=a++&&b++;
printf("\na=%d\nb=%d\nc=%d\n\n",a,b,c);
```

The output I obtained is given below,

```
a=1
b=0
c=0
```

This makes perfect sense because of short circuit evaluation.

The expression `a++` is post increment and `0` is returned to the logical and (`&&`). Hence the part `b++` is not evaluated since both `0 && 0` and 
`0 && 1` evaluates to `0`.

But here arises my doubt. The precedence value of operators clearly states that `++` is having higher precedence over `&&`. So my understanding was like this, both `a++` and b++ are evaluated and then `&&` only checks the result of expression `a++` to come to a decision. But this has not happened only `a++` is evaluated here.

What is the reason for this behavior? Does `&&` being a sequence point has something to do with this behavior? If so why we say that `&&` is having lower precedence than `++`?

Comment: there is one more rule that is above them,  a++ will only increment after a statement has executed. So, whatever its precedence is, its going to be incremenmted  after statment is finished.

Comment: Wow, this is a nasty trap.

Comment: Apart from the interesting language aspects of this question, I would recommend making your code immediately legible and obvious. At present this is not the case.

Comment: I think it's sad that such code gets ANY upvotes.

Comment: @saurabhagarwal `a++` will increment at some indeterminate time between when `a` is evaluated and when the statement finishes. That's why you can't use `a` again within the same expression (before or after the `a++`).

Comment: To be honest, I think it's sad that we've had two people complaining about the code instead of [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31779410/edit) the post. (To hold off obvious responses: I'll leave prettifying to people who actually work with the language.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are confused about **precedence** and **order of evaluation**.

Precedence defines how the operators are grouped, i.e

```
c = a++ && b++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
c = ((a++) && (b++));
```

Order of evaluation defines how the expression is evaluated, the short circuit of `&&` means `a++` is evaluated first, if it's zero, the end; if it's not zero, `b++` is then evaluated.

---

As another example:

```
c = (a++) + (b++);
```

Is `a++` evaluated before `b++`? The answer is we don't know. Most operators don't define the order of evaluation. `&&` is one of the few operators that do define. (The rest are `||`, `,` and `?:`)

Comment: Another way to say this is that && defines a sequence point after the evaluation of its left argument and before that of its second argument. There is no sequence point defined for +. Wikipedia has a good article about sequence points.

Answer (score 4):

There are two concepts here - order of precedence and order of evaluation. Order of precedence will have an impact only if an expression (or sub-expression) is evaluated.

In general, the order of evaluation is not sequenced. Given an operator, its operands can be evaluated in any order. The arguments of a function can be evaluated in any order.

From the C++ Standard:

> **1.9 Program execution**
>
> 15 Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.

and

> **8.3.6 Default arguments**
>
> 9 Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

For the logical AND operator, `&&`, the C++11 standard says:

> **5.14 Logical AND operator**
>
> 1 The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to type `bool` (Clause 4). The result is `true` if both operands are `true` and `false` otherwise. Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`.

Similar exception is specified for the logical OR operator, `||`.

Since `b++` is not evaluated due to short circuiting of the expression because of `&&` operator, the order of precedence of the operators has no significance in this particular case.

Comment: saying "order of precedence" confuses the issue, "order of evaluation" and "precedence" need to be kept separate